# median value of 3D array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, median

I'm interesting in the way to get median of 3D array (cube).

While I understand how to calculate median of simple 1D array, I could not find the way how it should work in 3 dimensions.

Could anybody explain how to find median value of 3D, please.

Thanks.

Comment: From an answer that has been deleted but might still be useful for readers (was useful to me): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a median of a 3D array. There's only a median of a list of numbers. If your list is stored as a 3D array, that's of little consequence. Just copy all the elements into a 1D array, sort it, and take the middle element.

Comment: Or even just index your 3D array with a single index (using `/` and `%` to get the individual dimensions' indices).

Comment: @GuyGreer: In most programming languages I know, it would make calling the sort routine quite difficult. Unless this is a huuge array, I think I'd opt for the less optimized but simpler approach of copying the array.

Comment: Agreed, I wasn't correcting you, rather just adding another possibility.  It's not necessarily that much more difficult if you can wrap the 3D array in another class then define its member access function accordingly.  As you say, however, this may or may not be possible.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan, well I was asked about median in 3 dimensions, so I'm  pretty sure that it's exist